# Parallel computation with dask when dataframe column needs to be computed

Tags: python, pandas, dask, fastparquet

I've got a 360 million record dataframe of bird sighting data 
[image]
and I'd like to compute the centroid of each bird species as a function of yearday using `dask` in a distributed way.

I would like to do:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['VERNACULARNAME', 'yearday']).mean()
```

but I need to first compute `yearday`, and I can't figure out if there is a way to do this on the fly with `dask`.  I was hoping that dask might just persist the new data to the `dask` workers, but when I try:

```
def yearday(r):
    r['yearday'] = dt.datetime(r['YEAR'], r['MONTH'], r['DAY']).timetuple().tm_yday
    return r

df.apply(yearday, axis=1).persist()
```

it does not scale.

If someone wants to actually try, the data can be loaded like this:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_parquet('s3://esipfed/ebird/EOD_CLO_2016.parq.gz',
            storage_options={'anon': True, 'use_ssl': False})
```

Note: Although I called this dataset `EOD_CLO_2016.parq.gz`, it is chunked over many objects in the S3 bucket to facilitate parallelization.   Each chunk is gzipped.

Is there any way to do this compuation on the fly in a distributed way or do I need to write another data file with the yearday column before I use `groupby` to do the scalable part?

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not scale"?

Comment: how do you run your code ? A complete but reduced example which allows reproduction would be very helpful.

Comment: We don't have the credential to read the file you shared.

Comment: @user32185, the data should be public read.  I added the `storage_options` above. Does that help?

Comment: @mdurrant, I guess actually the workers are working, but it's super slow.  The full notebook is here: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/rsignell-usgs/e0fd0345c322b493dc1d8f4b1594aaa1

Comment: Why do you use `apply` for `yearday`? Assuming `YEAR, MONTH, DAY` are `str` I'd rather try something like `df["dayofyear"] = df['YEAR'] +"-"+df["MONTH"].str.zfill(2)+"-"+df["DAY"].str.zfill(2)` then `df["dayofyear"] = df["date"].astype("M8[us]).dt.dayofyear`

Comment: An even faster method using recent `pandas` versions that works with numeric `YEAR, MONTH, DAY` is `df['yearday'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY']]).dt.dayofyear`. You now need to adapt this case for `dask`.

Comment: @RichSignell apparently the bicket doesn't exist anymore. Do you mind to update the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following what you did on your [notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/rsignell-usgs/e0fd0345c322b493dc1d8f4b1594aaa1) I'd modify the steps before the `groupby` in the following way

```
df = dd.read_parquet('s3://esipfed/ebird/EOD_CLO_2016.parq.gz',
                     columns=['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'DECIMALLATITUDE',
                              'DECIMALLONGITUDE', 'VERNACULARNAME'],
                     storage_options={'anon': True, 'use_ssl': False})

df = df.map_partitions(lambda df: df.assign(yearday=pd.to_datetime(df[['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY']]).dt.dayofyear,
                                            lat=np.deg2rad(df['DECIMALLATITUDE'].values),
                                            lon=np.deg2rad(df['DECIMALLONGITUDE'].values)),

                        meta={'YEAR':'i8', 'MONTH':'i8', 'DAY':'i8',
                              'DECIMALLATITUDE':'f8','DECIMALLONGITUDE':'f8',
                              'VERNACULARNAME':'object',
                              'yearday':'i8', 'lat':'f8', 'lon':'f8'})

df = df.map_partitions(lambda df :df.assign(x=np.cos(df['lat'].values) * np.cos(df['lon'].values),
                                            y=np.cos(df['lat'].values) * np.sin(df['lon'].values),
                                            z=np.sin(df['lat'].values)),
                       meta={'YEAR':'i8', 'MONTH':'i8', 'DAY':'i8',
                              'DECIMALLATITUDE':'f8','DECIMALLONGITUDE':'f8',
                              'VERNACULARNAME':'object',
                              'yearday':'i8', 'lat':'f8', 'lon':'f8',
                              'x':'f8', 'y':'f8', 'z':'f8'})
```

**UPDATE:** I'm not sure if is a good idea to have your data stored as a single and zipped file instead of multiple files. Have you consider different options?

**UPDATE 2:** Given that the conversion from degrees to radians is linear you can calculate `lon, lat` and then `x,y,z` after the `groupby`.

Comment: Wow @user32185, this works great!  I didn't know about `map_partitions`.  It's good to have the data stored in multiple objects on the cloud so the different workers can extract and work the chunks efficiently.   I need to calculate x,y,z before the groupby because it's not linear -- there are products of sin and cos involved

Comment: You're welcome. I'm still struggling with many things with dask and I personally find a little annoying the verbosity of `meta`. Then off course sin and cos are not linear but, I'm guessing, your final aim with x,y,z is 3D-plotting the position of bird on a given yearday and you have lat and lon as mean you should be fine.
Finally might I ask if you set the `kubeCluster` by yourself or someone did for you? I'm looking for a tutorial to build my own on AWS.

Comment: To get the centroid from lat,lon points, you can't just take the mean.  The only reason I'm computing spherical earth x,y,z is to then calculate the lon,lat centroid.   Yes, I set up my own cluster on AWS, using the zero2jupyterhub instructions, along with the pangeo instructions.  Please checkout http://pangeo.io and/or send me email offline for further info.